# Multiple Filters relevant on each other

Tags: sapui5

So in my application I have a filter bar with around 9 different filters and a very large database, lets say a million line items.

I was wondering if it was possible to have the filters relevant and if there is an easy way to do this.

An example:
lets say we have 3 fields of Location, Age & team. If my first filter Location is set to a location for example UK, then the Age and Team filters should only show the Age and Teams for people that live in the UK.

UK,31,A.
UK,30,B.
US,20,A.
US,20,C.

So in the above if UK was selected then only age 31 and 30 is shown and team would only show A and B. If you selected Age 31 as well as UK then only A should be available from team.

Is this something that is easy to implement or is there a standard way of doing this.

The only thing I can think of, is using filters and sending them as a gateway service to return the data. The issue there is that we have 1million items, so I don't know what the performance will be like.

Does anyone know of any approaches for this, I'm thinking to just push back on the requirement, but then it will become confusing for users.

Comment: I've only ever done the oData filtering as you suggested. You could quickly check with a `select distinct age where location = 'UK'` in a test program what the performance is like though. If it's HANA it might be fast enough to do in a CDS based association

Comment: not sure if you want an answer for frontend, gateway or backend

Comment: I'm a front end developer but happy with an answer for any of them. What would be the best approach. I can only think of the approach above, was wondering if there was any other way.

Comment: You are right using filters in the frontend. You could set some filters as mandatory to reduce the DB load. But in the end you should get the information from Backend by Skip and Top (pagination). In this case the user has his relevant information and the millions of data do not matter.